# calling a function in python got nothing instead

Tags: python, function, class

I got a code like this.

```
....
class SocketWatcher(Thread):
    ....
    def run(self):
       ....
       TicketCounter.increment()  # I try to get this function  
       ...
....
class TicketCounter(Thread):
    ....
    def increment(self):
    ...
```

when I run the program I got this error.

```
TypeError: unbound method increment() must be called with TicketCounter instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

i there any way that I can call the increment() function from TicketCounter Class to the SocketWatcher Class? or Does my calling is wrong...

Comment: The comment is quite obvious. You could have read it and Googled around a bit to get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You must create an instance of the class `TicketCounter` first before you can call any functions from it:

```
class SocketWatcher(Thread):
    ....
    def run(self):
       ....
       myinstance = TicketCounter()
       myinstance.increment()
```

Otherwise the method is not bound anywhere. Creating an instance binds the method to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions are part of the instances of a Class. So whenever you want to call you must always call it with an instance of the Class and not the Class name itself.

You could do:

`TicketCounter().increment()`

What this does is that it initialises an object and then calls this function. The following example will make it clear.

```
class Ticket:

    def __init__(self):

        print 'Object has been initialised'

    def counter(self):

        print "The function counter has been invoked"
```

And the output to illustrate this:

```
>>> Ticket().counter()
Object has been initialised
The function counter has been invoked
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing self, so I'm assuming that you need to create an instance. But if the method really doesn't need an instance then you can use the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorators and your code would work:

```
class TicketCounter(Thread):
    @classmethod
    def increment(cls):
        ...
```

or

```
class TicketCounter(Thread):
    @staticmethod
    def increment():
        ...
```

both can be called as `TicketCounter.increment()`